# Sorting a map of objects by object variables

Tags: c++, list, sorting, maps

I have these classes: `SortBy`, `Employee`, `Company` and `Database`. `Database` has `Database::Sorted` method that will use `SortBy` class and sort depending on added key. `Database` has a `map<string,Company*> m_companies` of companies and that is the map I need to sort. I can have one key or multiple keys.

Sorting by using multiple keys (for example first by name and then by age) is not a big problem, however, I'm not sure how I should attack this problem with maps and objects as a beginner to OOP.

Let's say I have:

```
John, 27, 300, Washington
Jane, 20, 500, Fargo
Anna, 44, 150, Stanford
Kyle, 44, 150, Paris
```

then:

```
assert( EqualLists( a.Sorted("Apple", CSortBy()
                                    .AddKey(CSortBy::by_age,true)
                                    .AddKey(CsortBy::by_address,true) ),
                        list<CEmployee> {

                            CEmployee("Jane", 20, 500, "Fargo", "Apple"),
                            CEmployee("John", 27, 300, "Washington", "Apple"),
                            CEmployee("Kyle", 44, 150, "Paris", "Apple"),
                            CEmployee("Anna", 44, 150, "Stanford", "Apple")
                        }
                        ) );
```

in this case I will sort first by age and then by address, both times ascending.

[**FULL CODE HERE**](https://pastebin.com/zNUHds7L).

What's the quickest way to do this?

Comment: You create a `list<CEmployee>` that copied the elements from the `map` (check the reference for `std::list`s constructor to see how) and then just `list.sort(comparator)` with the proper comparator.

Comment: My assignment requires me to sort it through the `CSortyBy` class. Also I'm not sure how the `list.sort` would allow me to sort using one or multiple keys.

Comment: You can see what comparator [list.sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) wants. You can use a lambda (or struct if C++11 is not allowed) that holds a reference to the `CSortBy` object and uses it to produce the correct behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the `list.sort` part fully, could you please give me an example of how the `list.sort` would look like if I wanted to sort by address and by salary ascending?

Comment: Something like `list.sort([](const CEmployee &lhs, const CEmployee &rhs){ return std::tie(lhs.address, lhs.salary) < std::tie(rhs.address, rhs.salary); });`. Of course you would need to add some logic to do the right thing depending on what `CSortBy` says you should sort by and not hardcode the address+salary sort order.